# How to change a value in a source of Executable file

Tags: vb.net, exe

I have a form called messageselector that contains a Textbox and Button, in addition it has an executable source file, called showmessage.exe, it's job is to show a messagebox:

```
Dim msgText As String = "Hello World!"
MsgBox(msgText)
```

when i run the form messageselector and click it's button, it executes showmessage.exe, and i get the message "Hello World!".

i didn't use a console application with parameters method because i need to know how to modify
the source of showmessage.exe

now i need to know:

how can i make it show me the text of textbox instead of "Hello World!"?

should it be a dynamic value in the very sources of showmessage.exe file, or can i modify it within messageselector code

any help appreciated, thank you so much.

Comment: Why you need a external .exe file to show a msg ?

Comment: It's a matter of the Client who asked me to make the program